# I don't know how to put blocks (or buttons) up in order.(up and down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't speak english very well.
so please understand me.. sorry..

Um.. I am develop the image below(attached image file)
[image]
I drawed my question contents.

I want to arrange block(or button) up and down time about.
I don't know how to make..
I don't know how to get **access** to.
(I want to use like javascript or jquery.
my project use front-end's language like javascript or jquery
Please excuse me.)

please show how..
Thank you for my question.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. 지금까지 시도한 것을 보여주십시오.

Comment: There is no result of the development because we don't know how to approach it. I'm so sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me but if you want to draw rectangle like chess board then you can do like below.

```js
for (var i=0; i< 8; i++){
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").appendChild(document.createElement("div")).style.backgroundColor = parseInt((i / 4) + i) % 2 == 0 ? 'blue' : 'none';    
}
```

```css
#mainDiv
{
    width:120px;
    height:160px;
}

div
{
 width:30px;
 height:20px;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You will need to adjust the pixels to get the buttons exactly where you want.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <button id="one" style="margin-left:20px;">one</button><button id="two" style="margin-left:20px;">two</button><button id="three" style="margin-left:30px;">three</button><br />
  <button id="four" style="margin-left:45px;">Four</button><button id="five" style="margin-left:40px;">Five</button>
</body>
</html>
```